# CentOS 6.5 not bringing up network interface automatically after reboot [ifup eth0]

Tags: networking, centos, interface

I am having this issue with many of my CentOS servers where after a reboot the network interface fails to come up automatically. This is a big problem for me since I need to drive to the datacenter every time when this happens as a result from a remote reboot. Then on the console eth0 is down and I have to ifup this manually. Is there a specific config file I can check to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: One thing to look at is to make sure the designation of NIC device is consistent across reboots. There's like about 3 places you need to look at for this. I don't remember offhand what they are - I've got them written down at my other job, so later I'll take a look and post here. The reason I say this is because I've had this happen before a number of times, and it turned out that the OS was relabeling "eth1" as "eth0" and vice-versa during reboot.  ... Annoying! But there's a way to force it to be consistent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ensure that the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` has the line

`ONBOOT="yes"`

See [9.2. Interface Configuration Files](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html) for details.

Comment: Also worked on CentOS 7.2.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure `ONBOOT="yes"` is set in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` also check that 
`NetworkManager` or `network`  (whichever you use) is started on boot.

`chkconfig NetworkManager on`  or `chkconfig network on`

Answer (score 4):

Configuration file must have right privileges also:

```
sudo chmod 0755 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*
```

At `/etc/sysconfig/network` can have those lines:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=myhostname.mydomain
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
```

Comment: I needed chmod 0755 if* it was absolutely critical I was getting ifdown /ifup,ifpost 'permission denied' this solution here was the only one  I was able to Google. I'd inadvertently backed-up  and restored the config files without a cp -p (preserve)